# Delete item from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to delete a item from my table in my Controller
The problem is i dont use a scope i use a Function Controller. 
If i try to add a function there is crashed and give a error.

Hope you guys can help me

homeController:

```
// homeController.js


(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('homeController', homeController);


    function homeController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.autos = [
            {id: 1, 'Omschrijving': 'A 180', Prijs: '24.242 € ', Type: 'A'},
            {id: 2, 'Omschrijving': 'A 180 CDI BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '26.015 € ', Type: 'A'},
            {id: 3, 'Omschrijving': 'B 200 CDI BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '30.129 € ', Type: 'B'},
            {id: 4, 'Omschrijving': 'C 250 CGI BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '40.414 € ', Type: 'C'},
            {id: 5, 'Omschrijving': 'C 300 CDI 4MATIC BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '48.642 € ', Type: 'C'},
            {id: 6, 'Omschrijving': 'C 350 CGI 4MATIC BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '50.941 € ', Type: 'C'},
            {id: 7, 'Omschrijving': 'CL 500 CDI 4MATIC BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '129.954 € ', Type: 'CL'},
            {id: 8, 'Omschrijving': 'CL 600', Prijs: '170.489 € ', Type: 'CL'}
        ];
    }


};
})();
```

home.html

```
<div>
    <table style="text-align: left;">
    <th>
    Omschrijving
    </th>
    <th>
    Prijs
    </th>
    <th>
    Type
    </th>
        <tr ng-repeat="autos in homeCtrl.autos">
        <td width="75%">
            <a ng-href="#/detail/{{autos.id}}">
            {{ autos.Omschrijving }}
            </a>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
            {{ autos.Prijs }}
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
            {{ autos.Type}}
            </td>
            <td>
            <a ng-click="delete(something)">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#/add">Auto Toevoegen</a>

</div>
```

So basicly i just need to know how i can add a function in my view and my controller to delete a item.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha
well yeah tried to work with scope everything, but get errors in my controller than. There should be a othre way only problem is i have no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // homeController.js


(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('homeController', homeController);


    function homeController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.autos = [
            {id: 1, 'Omschrijving': 'A 180', Prijs: '24.242 € ', Type: 'A'},
            {id: 2, 'Omschrijving': 'A 180 CDI BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '26.015 € ', Type: 'A'},
            {id: 3, 'Omschrijving': 'B 200 CDI BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '30.129 € ', Type: 'B'},
            {id: 4, 'Omschrijving': 'C 250 CGI BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '40.414 € ', Type: 'C'},
            {id: 5, 'Omschrijving': 'C 300 CDI 4MATIC BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '48.642 € ', Type: 'C'},
            {id: 6, 'Omschrijving': 'C 350 CGI 4MATIC BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '50.941 € ', Type: 'C'},
            {id: 7, 'Omschrijving': 'CL 500 CDI 4MATIC BlueEFFICIENCY', Prijs: '129.954 € ', Type: 'CL'},
            {id: 8, 'Omschrijving': 'CL 600', Prijs: '170.489 € ', Type: 'CL'}
        ];

        vm.delete = function(id){
            // delete vm.autos[id];
           vm.autos.splice(id-1, 1); // this is better
        }
    }



})();
```

home.html

```
<div>
    <table style="text-align: left;">
    <th>
    Omschrijving
    </th>
    <th>
    Prijs
    </th>
    <th>
    Type
    </th>
        <tr ng-repeat="autos in homeCtrl.autos">
        <td width="75%">
            <a ng-href="#/detail/{{autos.id}}">
            {{ autos.Omschrijving }}
            </a>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
            {{ autos.Prijs }}
            </td>
            <td width="25%">
            {{ autos.Type}}
            </td>
            <td>
            <a ng-click="homeCtrl.delete(autos.id)">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#/add">Auto Toevoegen</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Well that works the only problem is i cant press it twice if i want to delete a othre car it gives the error:
 Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: autos in homeCtrl.autos, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined

Comment: you can use "track by" in ng-repeat in case if  redundant id's exists. 

ie, use  <tr ng-repeat="autos in homeCtrl.autos track by autos.id">

instead of  <tr ng-repeat="autos in homeCtrl.autos">

Comment: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: autos in homeCtrl.autos track by autos.id, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: undefined
still same error

Comment: Well with you information i solved it you told me to put:
 <tr ng-repeat="autos in homeCtrl.autos track by autos.id">
i still recieved an error on the autos.id
Now i changed it to
 <tr ng-repeat="autos in homeCtrl.autos track by $index">
And everything is solved i thank you